# How to send a video stream to a server in C#?

Tags: c#, video, video-streaming

I made a Windows Form Application which captures video stream from my webcam and saves it as an .avi file.(I used EMGUCV for that).
How do i connect my client application to a server in order to send the video ? 
I have no experience with sockets and client-server communication. 
Any ideas, code samples, links will be useful.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the server. If it's an FTP server (which would be adequate for a video upload), use the `WebClient` object with the `STOR` method:

```
    void Upload(string ftpServer, string userName, string password, string filename)
    {
        using(var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            client.UploadFile(new Uri(ftpServer + "/" + new FileInfo(filename).Name), "STOR", filename);
        }
    }
```

More info [on the official documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).